# index.html.erb is not rendering properly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render

I made a project where the index.html.erb is not rendering properly and when I am using application.html.erb and when I remove that file everything works fine

```
   Home Controller
   class HomeController < ApplicationController
   end

   Routes file
   Rails.application.routes.draw do
   # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
   root "home#index"
   resources :posts
   end

   application.html.erb
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Project</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
 </head>

 <body>
 <%= yield%>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"index.html.erb is not rendering properly"_ - can you add some more details about exactly what isn't working?

Comment: @mikej This is after adding the application.html.erb[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/akdo20maryywjn5/After.jpg?dl=0) and this is before adding the application.html.erb[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qg4y72qr9myt4vq/Before.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: Your routes include `root "home#index"`, but you don't have the index method defined in HomeController, ie. `def index ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define the `index` action that you are referencing in your `routes.rb` in `HomeController`. To do this, you'd have to define an `index` method in `HomeController`, so:

```
# home_controller.rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index; end
end
```